# "Mute tweets" en français

Tags: traduction

On trouve dans certaines applications Twitter, on trouve une fonctionnalité nommée "Mute Tweets". Elle consiste à retirer des timelines des tweets contenants des éléments que l'utilisateur ne veut pas voir dans sa timeline (certains mots, hashtags...).

J'aide à la traduction d'une application Twitter contenant cette fonctionnalité et je ne sais pas comment traduire le nom de la fonctionnalité en français. Je sais bien que *mute* signifie "*rendre muet*" mais je ne trouve pas que cette traduction ait du sens pour un tweet. "*Banissement*" me semblerait plus indiqué.

D'où ma question : comment traduiriez-vous le "*mute*" de "*mute tweets*" ?

Comment: « Descendre l'oiseau » -- mute = muet, d'où silence, un silencieux, un oiseau... bon O.K.! J'ai pas de bonne réponse.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

J'ai une très forte impression que Twitter a opté pour *mute* plutôt que pour le traditionnel *hide* en raison de toutes les connotations aviaires dont s'est doté ce site. Le logo est un oiseau et les microblogues sont des « tweets », des gazouillis si l'on francise littéralement. Donc *mute tweets*, c'est thématique.

Or, *tweet* n'a pas été francisé, choix de Twitter. On perd alors toute la notion de gazouillis et de thème. De ce fait, je ne vois pas pourquoi on ne pourrait pas mettre la littéralité et *mute* de côté et opter pour « **cacher ces tweets** », ou « **ignorer ces tweets** ».

Cependant, si on veut absolument garder la notion de *mute*, on peut penser à « assourdir ».

Comment: Oui, j'avais cherché quelque chose autour de *tweets silencieux* ou *faire taire ces tweets* mais sans rien trouver de satisfaisant. Je trouve l'analyse de Laure très bonne sur l'abandon de la métaphore aviaire/auditive. (+1)

Comment: "**Ignorer les tweets**" me semble une très bonne traduction. Je pense que je vais choisir cette traduction pour "*mute tweets*" même si j'hésite avec "**Ecarter les tweets**" qui m'est venu plus tard. *Cacher* est bien aussi mais *ignorer* est mieux.

Pour ce qui est du nom la fonctionnalité, je pense que je vais garder le "*Mute*" anglais et ne pas le franciser (à l'instar de *tweet*).

Merci pour la réponse.

Answer (score 0):

Est-ce que ce genre de fonctions ne s'appelle pas plutôt *bloquer* (dans les deux langues), habituellement?

Comment: Si même c'était le cas, « X devrait s'appeller Y » me semble *au mieux* une mauvaise réponse à « comment traduire X ? ».